# Initiate function on page load

Tags: reactjs

I have a function that gets some data when it is initiated. This can be done by a click even on a button, e.g.:

```
<button type="button" onClick={fetchData}>Get data</button>
```

Basically it is just a function given by:

```
function fetchData(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    <something POST to get data>
}
```

All of this is working as intended. However, the data is only fetched when the button is clicked. I would like for the data to be fetched on load as well so there is actually some data presented before the button is clicked.

I thought I could just say:

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetchData()
}, [])
```

But that doesn't seem to work. However, if I take everything inside the function, and replace it with the `fetchData()` in the `useEffect`, then it works. But I don't feel like changing stuff twice every time the function needs updates etc.

So what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Check your browser console. Chances are, you are calling `fetchData()` without any arguments, which causes an error because `e` will be undefined and `e.preventDefault()` will throw an error.

Comment: Hmmm, it says: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'preventDefault')`

Comment: Precisely as what I have expected. You need to remove the `e.preventDefault()` in your fetch data function.

Comment: Or invoke it conditionally: `if (e && e.preventDefault) { e.preventDefault() }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because when you're calling `fetchData()` in `useEffect`, no argument is being provided to the function. Yet in the function you are expecting the first argument to be present and calling it with `e.preventDefault()`. Since `e` will be undefined, attempting to access a key/property inside `undefined` will throw an error.

There are two solutions:

1. Only invoke functions stored in `e` when it is not undefined
2. Write a separate handler for the click event binding

---

### Solution 1: Use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

By first checking if `e` is null or undefined, we can prevent attempting to access a key/property on it:

```
function fetchData(e) {
    e?.preventDefault();
    // Additional fetching logic
}
```

If you want to also support browsers that do not support optional chaining, then using the [logical AND operand (`&&`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND) to perform lazy evaluation / short-circuiting will also work:

```
function fetchData(e) {
    e && e.preventDefault();
    // Additional fetching logic
}
```

### Solution 2: Separate event handlers for button

Remove `e` from your fetchData function completely:

```
function fetchData() {
    // Additional fetching logic
}
```

...and prevent the default event at the level of the click handler:

```
const onClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    fetchData();
}

<button type="button" onClick={onClick}>Get data</button>
```